# Ubuntu Server 22.04 wrong screen resolution except in recovery mode

Tags: server, grub2, display-resolution

When I log in locally to Ubuntu Server 22.04 (i.e. with screen, keyboard etc attached) the system is using a screen depth about 8 lines more than the display can handle, so these line aren't visible until they roll into view. This makes things pretty difficult to use. If I boot into recovery mode then the screen depth is correct.

I've tried using the various grub parameters - GRUB_TERMINAL, GRUB_GFXMODE, etc, using the resolution info from `videoinfo`, with no effect. Perhaps this isn't a grub issue because halfway through the normal boot I can see the font changes and that seems to be the problem. Up to that point I think it's being handled correcly. In recovery mode this mid-boot font change doesn't happen.

As there's no graphical interface, advice I've read about xrandr and x11 doesn't apply. I've run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked this down to the Intel i915 video driver, which does not handle the monitor correctly (an old LG W2042S). The EFI mode works fine until the i915 driver is loaded, then it goes wrong. I used "nomodeset" in the grub parameters to prevent the driver being loaded:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

Now it works OK.